# Semi Circular Carousel

Tags: slider, carousel

How can I make this type of carousel? Is there any library?

I discover many libraries but did not find this type of carousel.[image: Like]

Comment: Welcome. Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement.

Comment: Also, library requests are off topic here. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.